# Find and replace string with regex

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

This may be a newbie regex question (still learning), but I'm trying to uncapitalize all the objects in my code (but not classes); i.e for the code snippet:

```
Bishop_Piece Bishop;

Bishop.move()...
```

I want it to instead be:

```
Bishop_Piece bishop;

bishop.move()...
```

What I tried:

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i  's/Bishop[;.]/bishop./g'
```

However this results in:

```
Bishop_Piece bishop.

bishop.move()...
```

Basically, I want the character after what I'm searching for (i.e Bishop), to be 'kept' (be it `;` or `.`), which is what explains the `bishop./g`.

Comment: When using sed, you can match `[;.]` with a capture group and return whatever you matched to the output in the same place it was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/Bishop\([;.]\)/bishop\1/g'
```

Note that the `\([;.]\)` here defines a capturing group whose value is referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern.

The `(...)` parentheses are escaped since this is a POSIX BRE compliant regular expression.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/wn1JjQ):

```sh
s='Bishop_Piece bishop;
bishop.move()...'
sed 's/Bishop\([;.]\)/bishop\1/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
Bishop_Piece bishop;
bishop.move()...
```

Comment: This works. I understand the solution was the ```\1``` part. Thanks!

Comment: (and the change of ```\([;.]\)``` for the find)